# Joining 2 tables: 1 row in [A] where not matching against multiple possible rows in [B]

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given these two data sets:

```
Table A 
ID      KA      ParentID
1001    1111    2001
1001    1112    2001
1003    1113    2002
1004    1114    2003
1005    NULL    2004

Table B
ID    KA
2001  1111
2001  2222
2002  1113
2003  1114
2004  4444
```

How can I join these two tables such that only the rows shown are ones that do not share the same KA value when A.ParentID and B.ID are the same?
The issue i'm running into when doing a left join it's only matching for the first match in table B.

The results i would expect back are along the lines of this:

```
A.ID    B.KA
1001    2222
1005    4444
```

Is it possible to do something along the lines of logic with this code?:

```
Select A.ID, B.KA
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.ParentID = B.ID AND A.KA NOT IN (B.KA)
```

Comment: what should the output be?

Comment: Expected output i have listed there in the middle @VamsiPrabhala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you need to filter out `ka` records that are in either table.  If so, here's one option using `except`:

```
select distinct a.id, b.ka
from a 
    join b on a.parentid = b.id 
except
select distinct a.id, b.ka
from a 
    join b on a.parentid = b.id 
where a.ka = b.ka
```

- [Online Demo](http://rextester.com/CQGA34255)

---

And another using `not exists`:

```
select distinct a.id, b.ka
from a 
    join b on a.parentid = b.id 
where not exists (
    select 1
    from a a2
    where a2.id = a.id and b.ka = a2.ka)
```

- [Another Demo](http://rextester.com/XHP22259)

Comment: I implemented your first solution and it worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
SELECT A.ID, B.KA
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.ParentID = B.ID AND A.KA <> B.KA
```